# How does Cisco router know the sum of delays in eigrp?

Tags: cisco, eigrp

I know one can use sh ip route command example below,

(r1) s2/0 -- s2/0 (r3) -- lo0 (r3)

so the delay from r1 to r3 lo0 would be sum of delay on s2/0 and delay on lo0 on r3.

it's easy for a person to look at the diagram and calculate, but how does r1 know lo0's delay to be added in the sum?

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, specifically.  EIGRP calculates routes based on the advertised metric, which includes the delay value.

[Here's an example](http://www.omnisecu.com/cisco-certified-network-associate-ccna/eigrp-metric-calculation-formula-example.php) of how it's calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. you are right, each router calculates metric for a route and advertises to it's neighbor.  In the end, the delay is sum of delay of each router interface.

Comment: If you've found this answers your question, consider accepting it so the question doesn't keep popping up in the list looking for an answer

Comment: Still having trouble understand thoroughly.  The metric advertised by a neighbor switch is calculated with both bandwidth and delay with the output interface for a route, how is bandwidth delay were separated when i was received when the receiving router doesn't know the neighbor router's interface bandwidth and delay specifically.

Comment: The router doesn't know the neighbor's bandwidth or delay individually.  It only knows the metric, and that's what the route decision is based on.

Comment: Thanks Ron. It actually shows the delay and min bandwidth-------IOU1#sh ip route 2.2.2.2
-------Routing entry for 2.2.2.0/24  Known via "eigrp 1", distance 90, metric 2297856, type internal
 --Redistributing via eigrp 1
-- Last update from 10.1.1.2 on Serial2/1, 00:00:07 ago
 -- Routing Descriptor Blocks:
 --* 10.1.1.2, from 10.1.1.2, 00:00:07 ago, via Serial2/1
     --Route metric is 2297856, traffic share count is 1
     --**Total delay is 25000 microseconds, minimum bandwidth is 1544 Kbit**
--Reliability 255/255, minimum MTU 1500 bytes
--Loading 1/255, Hops 1

Comment: Yes, my last comment was wrong.  Pretend I didn't say it ;)  EIGRP advertises the minimum bandwidth and total delay in the routing updates.  Thanks for making me look it up.

Comment: Ya saw it on Wireshark.  bandwidth and delay are advertised to neighbor for metric calculation.